# Target specific version of .NET framework at Visual Studio 2010 Solution level

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to target both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 in my Visual Studio 2010 solution.

I am aware that I can set the `<TargetFrameworkVersion />` in my project files, however this requires me to edit every project file before building the solution for a specific .NET framework version. Scott Dorman provides a macro which does the trick on his blog post [Visual Studio 2010 and Target Framework Version](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2010/04/21/visual-studio-2010-and-target-framework-version.aspx).

I am looking for a global solution where I don't have to change the setting in every project. Is it possible to change a central setting at the solution level to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Jon Skeet wrote, there is no apparent way to define the target framework at the solution level. However, this can be done by adding specific *configurations* to the solution, then editing the `*.csproj` files manually to specify the targets for every configuration, rather than globally for the whole project.

Here is a step-by-step guide:

1. Select *Build* - *Configuration Manager*.
2. In the *Active solution configuration* drop-down list, select  and enter a meaningful name (e.g. `Debug v3.5`) based on whatever existing settings you already have.
3. For each project file, open it in the editor (you can do this in Visual Studio, but you have to first right-click on it in the Solution Explorer and select *Unload Project*, then *Edit xyz.csproj*).
4. Find the `<PropertyGroup>` element which matches the configuration you have just created (for instance `Debug v3.5|AnyCPU`).
5. Add in the XML, for instance after the closing `</PlatformTarget>` element, the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` and `<TargetFrameworkProfile>` you need.
6. Save the file.
7. In the Solution Explorer, use the command *Reload Project* to make the project available again.

Here is a sample:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug v3.5|AnyCPU'">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug v3.5\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;DOTNET35</DefineConstants>
  ...
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  <TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that I also define the symbol `DOTNET35`, which allows me to write framework dependent `#if` statements in the source code. I had, for instance, a few pieces of code which relied on `System.Tuple` and by adding a minimalistic version of the class, I could back-port my .NET 4.0 application to .NET 3.5.

Here is my snippet:

```
#if DOTNET35
namespace System
{
    public class Tuple<T1, T2>
    {
        public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2)
        {
            this.item1 = item1;
            this.item2 = item2;
        }

        public T1 Item1
        {
            get
            {
                return this.item1;
            }
        }

        public T2 Item2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.item2;
            }
        }

        private readonly T1 item1;
        private readonly T2 item2;
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: +1: Great answer. It helped me tremendously. Incidentally, I also had a few pieces of code which relied on `System.Tuple`.

Comment: VS 2012 does not seem very happy about this

Answer (score 6):

Not that I'm aware of.

Note that a project can be part of multiple solutions - or can be built independently of *any* solution. Thus all a "solution level" option could really do would be to set the default when creating a new project.

If you hand-edit the project files, I *believe* you should be able to create a single project file with configurations for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4. (I've certainly done that for .NET 2 and .NET 3.5 before now.) Then you could have different solution-level configurations which target the relevant project-level configurations.

Comment: You are right, I should be able to add `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>` and `<TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>` directly into the conditional `<PropertyGroup>` elements. I was looking for an interactive way to do this, but VS2010 does not seem to surface this setting on a per-configuration basis.